# Google Sheets Array Formula Return results where there is No Blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this array formula in Google Sheets:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(K3:M3/A3),"")
```

[image]
I would like to return the results of table 2 only where there are no blanks in table 1

Here's my GoogleSheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XLaN7aD95zOZZqoq3hSyCXu-I40oea-t-WOJ_Gc2kAQ/edit#gid=0

How can I do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if(G3:I3="","",K3:M3/A3)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks work perfectly, If i wanted to do it the other way around where =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(if(CK7:FH7<>"","",FL7:GU7/A7)),"")

Comment: =ArrayFormula(if(G3:I3<>"",K3:M3/A3,""))

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( IF( (K3:M6*(G3:I6>0)/A3)>0, K3:M6*(G3:I6>0)/A3, "" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if()` and `iferror(1/0)`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( if( G3:I6, K3:M6, iferror(1/0) ) )
```